# What determines syntax highlighting happening in code blocks?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I've added the complete code at the bottom of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867555/best-way-to-do-variant-visitation-with-lambdas) with a simple test that the answerers help to produce (I want to do this as a sort of Stack Overflow best practice), but I'm noticing that there is no syntax highlighting for that code block. Is there something wrong that I've done or something I've missed that disabled it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax highlighting is determined by the tags or by language hints. In the linked question, you have

```
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->
```

turned off syntax highlighting for the error messages. After that, to get syntax highlighting again, you need to switch it on with a new language hint.

I added one before the `lambda_visitor.h` file, so its now highlighted as C++.